# RDG RPC 401 failure when not joining AD domain aka Workgroup mode

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

A vanilla Workgroup install of Windows Server 2008R1 and following many of available guides:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983949(v=ws.10).aspx

1. Full Computer Name set to `TSGSERVER.local`, Workgroup `WORKGROUP`.
2. Add roles for *Remote Desktop Services* and the *Remote Desktop Gateway*.
3. Create self-signed certificate.
4. Complete install.
5. Export certificate via MMC from `Local Computer/Personal/Certificates`.
6. Import certificate via MMC to `Local Computer/Trusted Root Certification Authorities`.
7. Test with `rpcping` on command line:

```
    rpcping -v 3
            -e 3388
            -t ncacn_http
            -s localhost
            -o RpcProxy=TSGSERVER.local
            -P "Administrator,WORKGROUP,Password1"
            -H NTLM -u NTLM
            -a connect
            -F ssl
            -B msstd:TSGSERVER.local
            -E
            -R None
```

Parameters taken from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772486(v=ws.10).aspx

And the RPC fails:

```
RPCPing v6.0. Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, 2002-2006
 Since you have specified the RPC/HTTP proxy echo only option (-E), the endpoint
/interface you have specified will be ignored as no calls will reach the RPC/HTT
P server
 RPCPing set Activity ID:  {0c934a78-201c-40a3-82e8-9700bd928be6}
 RPCPinging proxy server tsgserver.local with Echo Request Packet
 Setting autologon policy to high
 Sending ping to server
 Response from server received: 401
 Use Server Preffered Auth Scheme: 2
 Setting autologon policy to high
 Sending ping to server
 Response from server received: 401
 Client is not authorized to ping RPC proxy
 Ping failed
```

With the IIS log files being similarly informative:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-08-28 18:01:02
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2013-08-28 18:01:02 192.168.1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /Rpc/rpcproxy.dll - 443 - 192.168.1.1 MSRPC 401 2 5 514
2013-08-28 18:01:02 192.168.1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /Rpc/rpcproxy.dll - 443 - 192.168.1.1 MSRPC 401 2 5 0
```

What steps am I missing?

Without installing as a CA one naturally gets a certificate error:

```
RPCPing v6.0. Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, 2002-2006
 Since you have specified the RPC/HTTP proxy echo only option (-E), the endpoint
/interface you have specified will be ignored as no calls will reach the RPC/HTT
P server
 RPCPing set Activity ID:  {b8fc4006-a3e8-4b9f-aa18-e1b951c7fe9a}
 RPCPinging proxy server TSGSERVER.local with Echo Request Packet
 Setting autologon policy to high
 Sending ping to server
 Error 12175 : A security error occurred
 returned in WinHttpSendRequest
 Ping failed
```

This is documented in [KB 831051](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831051):

> The PRC Ping Utility test may have failed because the certificate is
>   not trusted or because it does not trust the certificate and root
>   authority. The server certificate subject from the RPC Proxy server
>   does not match the one that is specified by -B.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to specify `-u SChannel` with RPCping against an RDG endpoint

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `SChannel` requires a certificate on the client, I'm providing a password.